# How can I store timezone agnostic dates for sharing between R and Python using parquet?

Tags: python, r, parquet, apache-arrow

Right now I have the following issue. I want to share dataframes between R and Python that contain date-times but wish them to be timezone agnostic.

For example, from R I save a data.table (or data.frame) with the first column Date = as.POSIXct('2021-10-22'). This is a date that will show as being in your local timezone but for which the timezone has been set by default to ''.

When I write this out to a parquet file and read into a pandas dataframe it comes in as having been adjusted to UTC time but with no timezone information. I would like to be able to read it as being the original 2021-10-22 value with no timezone information.

Here is some code to illustrate the issue. I could take in the file and `.tz_localize(None)` the middle date column but it would be nicer to just be able to go agnostic to agnostic.

```r
rm(list=ls())

library(arrow)
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

outputFile <- 'D:/Temp/Test.parquet'
outputFileFeather <- 'D:/Temp/Test.feather'

dt <- data.table(Row=1:10, 
                 NoTZ = as.POSIXct('2021-10-22'), 
                 TZBris = as.POSIXct('2021-10-22', tz = 'Australia/Brisbane'),
                 TZNY = as.POSIXct('2021-10-22', tz = 'America/New_York'))

dt[, `:=`(NoTZ = NoTZ + hours(Row-1),
          TZBris = TZBris + hours(Row-1),
          TZNY = TZNY + hours(Row-1))]

write_parquet(dt, outputFile)
write_feather(dt, outputFileFeather)
```

```py
import pandas as pd

dfp = pd.read_parquet('d:/Temp/Test.parquet')
dff = pd.read_feather('d:/Temp/Test.feather')

print(dfp)
print(dff)
```

As can be seen the first column is timezone agnostic but has been adjusted to UTC. The second and 3rd demonstrate that the correct values can come through but only by using timezone aware/set values. What I would like to achieve is the first column being agnostic and unadjusted. I'd also like to be able to go R -> Python or Python -> R in this manner.

```
   Row                NoTZ                    TZBris                      TZNY
0    1 2021-10-21 14:00:00 2021-10-22 00:00:00+10:00 2021-10-22 00:00:00-04:00
1    2 2021-10-21 15:00:00 2021-10-22 01:00:00+10:00 2021-10-22 01:00:00-04:00
2    3 2021-10-21 16:00:00 2021-10-22 02:00:00+10:00 2021-10-22 02:00:00-04:00
3    4 2021-10-21 17:00:00 2021-10-22 03:00:00+10:00 2021-10-22 03:00:00-04:00
4    5 2021-10-21 18:00:00 2021-10-22 04:00:00+10:00 2021-10-22 04:00:00-04:00
5    6 2021-10-21 19:00:00 2021-10-22 05:00:00+10:00 2021-10-22 05:00:00-04:00
6    7 2021-10-21 20:00:00 2021-10-22 06:00:00+10:00 2021-10-22 06:00:00-04:00
7    8 2021-10-21 21:00:00 2021-10-22 07:00:00+10:00 2021-10-22 07:00:00-04:00
8    9 2021-10-21 22:00:00 2021-10-22 08:00:00+10:00 2021-10-22 08:00:00-04:00
9   10 2021-10-21 23:00:00 2021-10-22 09:00:00+10:00 2021-10-22 09:00:00-04:00
   Row                NoTZ                    TZBris                      TZNY
0    1 2021-10-21 14:00:00 2021-10-22 00:00:00+10:00 2021-10-22 00:00:00-04:00
1    2 2021-10-21 15:00:00 2021-10-22 01:00:00+10:00 2021-10-22 01:00:00-04:00
2    3 2021-10-21 16:00:00 2021-10-22 02:00:00+10:00 2021-10-22 02:00:00-04:00
3    4 2021-10-21 17:00:00 2021-10-22 03:00:00+10:00 2021-10-22 03:00:00-04:00
4    5 2021-10-21 18:00:00 2021-10-22 04:00:00+10:00 2021-10-22 04:00:00-04:00
5    6 2021-10-21 19:00:00 2021-10-22 05:00:00+10:00 2021-10-22 05:00:00-04:00
6    7 2021-10-21 20:00:00 2021-10-22 06:00:00+10:00 2021-10-22 06:00:00-04:00
7    8 2021-10-21 21:00:00 2021-10-22 07:00:00+10:00 2021-10-22 07:00:00-04:00
8    9 2021-10-21 22:00:00 2021-10-22 08:00:00+10:00 2021-10-22 08:00:00-04:00
9   10 2021-10-21 23:00:00 2021-10-22 09:00:00+10:00 2021-10-22 09:00:00-04:00
```

Answer (score 4):

As you've run into, there are complexities dealing with timezone-naive timestamps and how those should be interpreted, stored, and presented.

## (base) R's handling of `""` timezones

One issue here is that (base) R handles `""` timezones in interesting ways. As you've experienced "This is a date that will show as being in your local timezone but for which the timezone has been set by default to ''". Not only does R show the timestamp in that way, it actually stores it as an integer (seconds from the epoch) taking into account the R sessions local timezone (at the time that the conversion from string to `POSIXct` was made):

```
> as.POSIXct("2021-10-22")
[1] "2021-10-22 CDT"
> as.integer(as.POSIXct("2021-10-22"))
[1] 1634878800
>
> Sys.setenv(TZ="UTC")
>
> as.POSIXct("2021-10-22")
[1] "2021-10-22 UTC"
> as.integer(as.POSIXct("2021-10-22"))
[1] 1634860800
>
```

The integer stored doesn't change based on your local session timezone if you proactively set a timezone with `as.POSIXct()` like you show (i.e. the integer values stored are the same before and after changing the session timezone):

```
> as.POSIXct("2021-10-22", tz = "UTC")
[1] "2021-10-22 UTC"
> as.integer(as.POSIXct("2021-10-22", tz = "UTC"))
[1] 1634860800
> as.POSIXct("2021-10-22", tz = "Austrlaia/Brisbane")
[1] "2021-10-22 GMT"
There were 13 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> as.POSIXct("2021-10-22", tz = "Australia/Brisbane")
[1] "2021-10-22 AEST"
> as.integer(as.POSIXct("2021-10-22", tz = "Australia/Brisbane"))
[1] 1634824800
>
> Sys.setenv(TZ="UTC")
>
> as.POSIXct("2021-10-22", tz = "UTC")
[1] "2021-10-22 UTC"
> as.integer(as.POSIXct("2021-10-22", tz = "UTC"))
[1] 1634860800
> as.POSIXct("2021-10-22", tz = "Australia/Brisbane")
[1] "2021-10-22 AEST"
> as.integer(as.POSIXct("2021-10-22", tz = "Australia/Brisbane"))
[1] 1634824800
```

In fact, this can even lead to some interesting behaviors where saving a timestamp without a timezone and changing the session timezone returns different values:

```
> ts <- as.POSIXct("2021-10-22")
> ts
[1] "2021-10-22 CDT"
> Sys.setenv(TZ = "UTC")
> ts
[1] "2021-10-22 05:00:00 UTC"
> Sys.setenv(TZ = "Australia/Brisbane")
> ts
[1] "2021-10-22 15:00:00 AEST"
```

So you could think of R using the local timezone to convert from string to epoch, and [when `""` is used, it uses the local timezone](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.POSIXlt.html) (though it does not set that as the timezone in the `tzone` attribute!)

## Interaction with Arrow

When the arrow package converts these columns to the Arrow format, it recognizes that there is no timezone specified, and so writes a timezone-naive timestamp (and uses the integer value as usual). From [the C++ docs which both the R package and Python packages use under the hood:](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/api/datatype.html#_CPPv4N5arrow13TimestampTypeE)

> If a TimestampType is constructed without a timezone (or, equivalently, if the timezone supplied is an empty string) then the resulting Arrow field (column) is considered “timezone-naive”. The producer of a timezone-naive column may populate its constituent integer arrays with datetime values from any timezone; the consumer of a timezone-naive column should make no assumptions about the interoperability or comparability of the values of such a column with those of any other timestamp column or datetime value.

And [the pyarrow docs also describe something similar](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.array.html?highlight=timezone) though it was pointed out that the actual wording is confusing so I'm not posting it here. We are working on improving this.

And note that when looking at the Arrow array itself in R, you'll get what you're seeing in Python (that is, the timestamp will include an offset from 2021-10-22 based on your local timezone because the value from R is interpreted as if it were UTC even though it was actually converted with the local timezone by R when calling `as.POSIXct()` without a timezone):

```
> library(arrow, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
> df <- data.frame(NoTZ = as.POSIXct("2021-10-22"))
> tab <- Table$create(df)
> tab$NoTZ
ChunkedArray
[
  [
    2021-10-22 05:00:00.000000
  ]
]
```

## How to resolve this

1. You can set your R session timezone to UTC so that when R converts the string to a timestamp it does so at UTC (where Arrow will implicitly interpret timezone-naive timestamps):

```
> library(arrow, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
> Sys.setenv(TZ = "UTC")
> df <- data.frame(NoTZ = as.POSIXct("2021-10-22"))
> tab <- Table$create(df)
> tab$NoTZ
ChunkedArray
[
  [
    2021-10-22 00:00:00.000000
  ]
]
```

2. Use the actual date type to store your data. The question title refers to dates, but the code is using timestamps. If what you care about is dates only and not timestamps, this problem goes away:

```
> library(arrow, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
> df <- data.frame(NoTZ = as.Date("2021-10-22"))
> tab <- Table$create(df)
> tab$NoTZ
ChunkedArray
[
  [
    2021-10-22
  ]
]
```

3. If you are starting with dates, but do need the timestamp part (at 00:00:00), you can also do `as.POSIXct(as.Date("2021-10-22"))` which turns out to return a timestamp value as if the string were interpreted at UTC:

```
> as.POSIXct(as.Date("2021-10-22"))
[1] "2021-10-21 19:00:00 CDT"
> as.integer(as.POSIXct(as.Date("2021-10-22")))
[1] 1634860800
> Sys.setenv(TZ = "UTC")
> as.POSIXct(as.Date("2021-10-22"))
[1] "2021-10-22 UTC"
> as.integer(as.POSIXct(as.Date("2021-10-22")))
[1] 1634860800
```

And using Arrow:

```
> library(arrow, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
> df <- data.frame(NoTZ = as.POSIXct(as.Date("2021-10-22")))
> tab <- Table$create(df)
> tab$NoTZ
ChunkedArray
[
  [
    2021-10-22 00:00:00.000000
  ]
]
```

4. You can set timezones if you know them (though I acknowledge that this goes against storing timezone agnostic timestamps). If the data does contain timestamps and those have known timezones, this will lead to the least surprises due to differences in assumptions and interpretations like this.